# Facebook Pixels standard events with parameters

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm using the `Facebook Pixel` to track some events on my site as explained on: https://www.facebook.com/business/help/651294705016616/?ref=u2u

Seems like the only event which can accept other parameters is `Purchase`event. But here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/dynamic-product-ads/product-audiences/v2.6 we can see other events using other params:

```
fbq('track', 'ViewContent', {
  content_name: 'Really Fast Running Shoes',
  content_category: 'Apparel & Accessories > Shoes',
  content_ids: ['1234'],
  content_type: 'product',
  value: 0.50,
  currency: 'USD'
 });
```

To see more details about events and its parameters there is a link on the same web to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ads-for-websites/tag-api
But this web seems deprecated (as shown on the left menu).

Is it safe to use the parameters shown on this web?
I have not a `product catalog` I would like to use this parameters to filter my audience.

And finally, could I use my own parameters and filter my audience by my own parameters?